# Perform mysql left join on the resultset of inner join

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

A table

```
AID    PID  UID   
214    212  1009
213    212  1004
212    212  1002
211    210  1004
210    210  1003
```

F table

```
UID    FID
1000   1002
1002   1000
1000   1003
1003   1000
1000   1009
1009   1000
1009   1003
1003   1009
1004   1002
1002   1004
```

I can perform inner join on these tables like this to get the AID and PID from A table for each user's FID which can be obtained from the F table. Suppose my ID id 1000 then for me the actions performed by my friends would be

```
SELECT AID,PID from A inner join F on A.UID = F.FID where F.UID = '1000';
```

and the result will be

```
AID   PID
214   212
212   212
210   210
```

I need the PID to appear only once irrespective of which UID it relates to. Also i need the PID with the maximum AID associated with it.

If if try to do it using group by

```
SELECT AID,PID from A inner join F on A.UID = F.FID where F.UID = '1000'
 GROUP BY PID;
```

i will get

```
AID   PID
212   212
210   210
```

i want the result to be

```
AID   PID
214   212
210   210
```

Also i want to perform it using left join i.e left join on the resultset of the previous inner joined result. Reason i read that left join performs faster over group by. 
Please try to be efficient with your queries as A table has over 1.5 lakh tuples and F table has already over 5,000 tuples. These are going to drastically increase as will in future.

Comment: Please use some formatting for table contents because its unreadable

Comment: what's the primary key on both tables?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee primary keys  A(AID)   F(UID,FID)

Comment: @kunal use `MAX(AID) AS AID` instead of `AID`. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT AID, PID
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN F ON A.UID = F.FID
  WHERE F.UID = '1000'
  ORDER BY AID DESC 
) AS t
GROUP BY PID
```

//**EDIT**

Simplified version :)

```
SELECT MAX( AID ) AS AID , PID
FROM A
INNER JOIN F ON A.UID = F.FID
WHERE F.UID = '1000'
GROUP BY PID
```

Comment: your answer just selects the max AID what if other columns are also present along with AID and PID they will not correspond max(AID). please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select MAX(A.AID),PID 
from A left join F on (A.UID=F.FID) 
where F.UID=1000 
group by PID;
```

.. oh, I see @piotrekkr has thought of it just ahead of me :) only difference being the `LEFT JOIN`.

If you also want other columns corresponding to the MAX, you have to use a join of the table `A` to itself:

```
SELECT A.AID, A.PID, F.FID -- etc.
FROM A
LEFT JOIN A A2
 ON A.PID=A2.PID AND A.AID<A2.AID
LEFT JOIN F  -- may want to inner join here, up to you
 ON A.UID=F.FID
WHERE F.UID=1000
AND A2.AID IS NULL;
```

THE `A LEFT JOIN A A2 ON A.PID=A2.PID AND A.AID<A2.AID WHERE A2.AID IS NULL` is the key part -- it joins the table `A` to itself within each `PID` (that's the `GROUP BY PID` in the original query), and additionally requires that A's AID is less than A2's.

Since it's a left join, if there is an A.AID in A such that there is no larger AID (in A2) for that PID, then the A2.AID will be NULL. This is precisely the maximum AID.

Comment: your answer just selects the max AID what if other columns are also present along with AID and PID they will not correspond max(AID). please help.

Comment: Oh, you want corresponding columns too (your question didn't say so) -- I will update my answer.